# Segfault on Recursive Tree Traversal/Branch Deletion

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, segmentation-fault, delete-operator

I'm trying to clean the branches of a **tree**, each node stores an `occurrence` 
 value for each time the node has been visited during construction, "cleaning" in this sense refers to deleting branches after the point where two subsequent nodes both have only one `occurrence`:

So, a branch of `5->1->1->1` would become simply `5->1`. I'm using a **recursive tree traversal** (which works when printing all paths) and then a **recursive deletion** (which works when destructing the object):

```
void tree::cleanBranch(Node *node)
{
    if(!node)
        return;

    int cnt = 0;
    int ind = 0;
    // 4 possible subnodes
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if(node->subnodes[i]) {
            cnt++;
            ind = i;
        }
        if(cnt > 1)
            break;
    }

    // Only 1 subnode and both current and subnode have occurrence of 1
    if(cnt == 1 && node->occurrences == 1 && 
            node->subnodes[ind]->occurrences == 1) {
        delTree(node->subnodes[ind]);
        return;
    } 

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cleanBranch(node->subnodes[i]);
}
```

And the deletion function:

```
void tree::delTree(Node* node)
{
    if(node) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            delTree(node->subnodes[i]);
        delete node;
    }
}
```

However it segfaults immediately. I then created a simple tree, `5->1->1`, and it segfaulted on the first `delete` which was called upon the third node but both `cleanBranch()` and `delTree()` check that it is not null before deletion.

I feel I am missing something obvious, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

In response to **Qubit**:

They're really very simple to be honest, `tree`'s is:

```
tree() { root = new Node; }
```

referring to the member `Node *root`.

And `Node` itself has:

```
Node(): occurrences(0), subnodes(4)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        subnodes[i] = NULL;
}
```

Where `occurrences` is a `ulong` and `subnodes` is a `vector` of `Node*`'s.

In response to **Erik Alapää**:

I'm not currently but I'll shift it over and give it a crack.

Comment: Valgrind? If you run on Linux.

Comment: Can we see the constructor for the nodes?

Comment: I might be blind but I can't see the issue in what you have here. And I can't try because these are just fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code provided seems to be correct. May be something wrong in how you create the tree?

Assuming that Node is something like this

```
struct Node
{
    unsigned long occurrences = 0;
    vector<Node*> subnodes;

    Node(): occurrences(0), subnodes(4)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            subnodes[i] = NULL;
    }
};
```

and the tree creation something like this

```
// 5->1->1->1
Node* createTree()
{
    Node* root = new Node;
    root->occurrences = 5;

    Node* cur = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        cur->subnodes[0] = new Node;
        cur->subnodes[0]->occurrences = 1;
        cur = cur->subnodes[0];
    }
    return root;
}
```

(using your code style)
cleanBranch works OK.
Also add

```
node->subnodes[ind] = nullptr;
```

after

```
delTree(node->subnodes[ind]);
```

otherwise you will get GPF if you accidently call cleanBranch twice on the same tree.

BTW, consider to use unique_ptr instead of Node*.

Update:
Node obviously should have destructor like this

```
~Node()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < subnodes.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (subnodes[i])
        {
            delete subnodes[i];
            subnodes[i] = nullptr; // not nesessary with vector but =)
        }
    }
}
```

than you haven't to use delTree, just

```
delete node->subnodes[ind];
node->subnodes[ind] = nullptr;
```

Comment: I feel like quite the idiot, it was me missing the `nullptr` line that caused my printing function to segfault. Works a charm now, thanks a lot.

Comment: glad that it helped =)